# Postgres Error | COPY Command Disk Quota Exceeded

Tags: postgresql, copy, export-to-csv, psql

I have 2 tables with 7.7 million records and other with 160 million records.
I want dump of the tables on my NAS drive (700GB+ available memory). I'm using following command to export the data to csv file:

```
\COPY (select * from table_name) to '/path_to_nas_drive/test.csv' csv header;
```

After running the above command, it's throwing the issue

> Could not write COPY data : disk quota exceeded

Why it's throwing the error? is it because of the space issue on database server that it's not able to create buffer/temporary file or is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try scaling back the request and just getting one row just to make sure you can use COPY even for just one row:

```
\COPY (select * from table_name limit 1) to '/path_to_nas_drive/test.csv' csv header;
```

**You can also try compressing the output with gzip like so:**

```
psql -c "\COPY (select * from table_name) to stdout" yourdbname | gzip > /path_to_nas_drive/test.csv.gz
```

Comment: limit 1 is working, I'll try the second query and will update the result here

Answer (score 0):

It is a client issue, not a server issue.  "could not write COPY data" is generated by `psql`, and "disk quota exceeded" comes from the OS and is then passed on by `psql`.

So your NAS is telling you that you are not allowed to write as much to it as you would like to.  Maybe it has plenty of space, but it isn't going to give it to you, where "you" is whoever is running `psql`, not whoever is running PostgreSQL server.